# Running an application from an USB device

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm working on a proof-of-concept application, containing a WCF service with console host and client, both on a single USB device. On the same device I will also have the client application which will connect to this service. The service uses the entity framework to connect to the database, which in this POC will just return a list of names. If it works, it will be used for a larger project.

Creating the client and service was easy and this works well from USB. But getting the service to connect to the database isn't. I've found [this site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/180809ff-e5e5-4735-8f35-f0cc7c6cf838), suggesting that I should modify machine.config but that stops the XCopy deployment. This project cannot change any setting of the PC, so this suggestion is bad. I cannot create a deployment setup either. The whole thing just needs to run from USB disk.

So, how do I get it to run?

(The service just selects a list of names from the database, which it returns to the client. If this POC works, it will do far more complex things!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awww. Solved it. Just needed to add this to the .config file.

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"></remove>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" 
           invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" 
           description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
           type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Adding it to the local config file works just fine too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using an In Memory database (if it suits your application).Some time back i had worked on a project where a web application was given offline as a desktop product.We had used HSQLDB as the in memory database, and for us it worked well (the database was also small)

Comment: No, the in-memory database won't work. Too many tables and too much data that needs to be shared. Furthermore, I need a solution which can be enlarged to use a full SQL Server database as database replacement. (The compact edition will support at most 3 users, the full SQL Server version up to 2000 users.)